# Understanding the anonymous classes

Tags: php

Hello everyone i am reading a book for advance php i came accross anonymous classe, i don't understand how this work and how to pass data to function i am adding two examples
This example is understandable working fine

```
$object = new class {
 public function hello($message) {
 return "Hello $message";
 }
};
echo$object->hello('PHP');
```

I need help in this case

The preceding example shows an $object variable storing a reference to an instance
of an anonymous class. The more likely usage would be to directly pass the new
class to a function parameter, without storing it as a variable, as shown here:

```
$helper->sayHello(new class {
 public function hello($message) {
 return "Hello $message";
 }
});
```

I am getting error of undefine variable, can somebody explain to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend your code to be able to call this.

`$helper` must be an instance having the a `sayHello()` method.

```
class Helper
{
    public function sayHello($class): void
    {
        echo $class->hello("World");
    }
}

$helper = new Helper();

$helper->sayHello(new class {
    public function hello($message): string
    {
        return "Hello $message";
    }
});
```

#### Output

```
Hello World
```